# Netbeans how to fix Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, netbeans

So im inside of netbeans trying use a persistance unit and while im there I need to establish a connection to my database named "bankofmunster". Whenever I set the username to "root" and the host to "localhost" I get this error

Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bankofmunster?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL using com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))

Comment: Do the username and password work in other MySQL clients?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Where else could I check if it works?

Comment: What do you mean? Is NetBeans the only tool you have to manage your local MySQL Server? Don't you use MySQL Workbench, HeidiSQL or the official command-line utility?